# Remove empty rows in CSS files on build Visual Studio

Tags: css, visual-studio, sass, build, publish

Is it possible to remove empty/blank lines in specific files on build/publish in Visual Studio?
I have sass files compiled to css and I would like to remove all empty rows in that file on build/publish. I'm using WebCompiler in order to compile and minify the sass files but there is no option to do this with this tool. There is simply no sass output type that does what I'm looking for.

Comment: You say you already minify the files. So the empty lines should already be gone, right? I find the question is unclear.

Comment: Your right, in production the minified file is used but we also have a copy of the css file unminified in the project in order to make compares easier.